# How to add classes or ids to built-in idyll components

Tags: idyll

We have several button elements that we would like to style in different ways. We originally added styling to them in the `style.css` file by adding css to the `.button` tag. The problem with this is now we would like to add more buttons, but with different styles. Since we added the styling to `.button` they all end up looking the same. Is there any way to add classes or ids to built-in idyll components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the className property to a button like `[button className:”newName”]...[/button]`